# What are the file system of CD and DVD?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

We have NTFS, FAT etc for HDD.
So I just want to know what are the file systems of CD and DVD?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ISO9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660), of which Joliet, Rock Ridge and El Torito are extensions:

> The Rock Ridge extension to ISO 9660 adds support for POSIX file permissions and ownership, symbolic links, and longer file names; the Joliet extension adds support for longer file names and the Unicode character set; and the El Torito extension enables a disc to boot an x86 compatible system.

Comment: Thanks for replying..Is your answer common for both CD and DVD?

Comment: From the wikipedia page: DVDs may also use the ISO 9660 file system. However, the UDF file system is more appropriate on DVDs since it offers better support for the larger media and is better suited for modern operating systems needs.

Answer (score 4):

[ISO9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660) (CDFS) is widely used for CD's and [UDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format) is widely used for DVD's, although both standards are used for both media types.

Answer (score 1):

That would be [ISO 9660](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso9660). Many extensions are used though, the most common being [Joliet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joliet_(file_system)).

Answer (score 0):

Joliet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joliet_(file_system)

Answer (score 0):

- ISO9660 and its extensions Rock Ridge and Joliet (there also used to be a Romeo)
- UDF
- HFS and HFS+, mainly by and for Apple Mac machines.
- FAT 32 on DVD-RAM and BD-RE

CD-i has its own file system but it closely resembles ISO9660.
Video-DVD needs UDF but black box video players may have enough with the information in the IFO files.  FATX is used on XBox discs (not verified myself)

FYI: http://www.isobuster.com/help/file_systems